Are there modern non-blocking/non-freezing editors for Linux?
Most editors that I use (kate, gedit, vi, etc) were written in 20th century when files used to be local and all apps were using blocking file system operations, which means that UI freezes until read or write completes, but we live in connected century and most of my files are located on multiple remote file systems (NFS or SMB) - on several my own PCs, my co-worker's PCs, servers, PIs, Jetsons, etc. And they all intermittently go offline all the time. And when any of the remote file systems become unavailable, my kate or gedit freezes with the dreaded "Not Responding" message. And then I have to figure out which file system is frozen and unmount it to resume the editor and then re-mount when it comes back online.
I was suffering like this for decades until few years ago found a true 21st century editor: vscode - it never freezes! If a temporarily inaccessible file is already open, it allows me to continue working with it locally, otherwise it shows an empty screen until file becomes accessible again. This is perfect, and this is how all modern editors (and other apps) should be written - never freeze! But, I guess, nobody is going to rewrite the dinosaurs like kate and gedit and vi in modern ways. And vscode is an IDE and not a replacement for a general purpose editor.
I also tried gnome-text-editor on Ubuntu 24.04, opened a file from remote file system, then disconnected the remote device, then pressed Ctrl+O and the Text Editor app (gnome-text-editor) froze with a "Not Responding" message. VSCode does not freeze in this situation (even if the File Open dialog itself froze I was able to cancel it and continue working with the rest of my files).
So, my question is whether you know a decent, modern, general purpose text editor, which does not freeze?

What's stopping you from using VS Code as a general purpose text editor?

The way I am using VSCode is to open a folder with my project and it allows me to open files in this folder. But I need to open files from different corners of my file systems (logs, config files, documents, etc) and VSCode does not let me organize them as well as kate does. I can open files from other dirs, but they do not appear in the document list on the left, like they do in kate. May be I am using vscode incorrectly?

One work around is to save your files locally and sync the folder with the remote server and or coworkers' account.

I have used unison before for syncing folders and files. It is available in both Ubuntu and Raspberry Pi OS repositories.

@user68186  I use rsync all the time (may try unison later), but it is not a substitute to being able to view logs directly on remote device, edit config files directly on remove device, edit scripts and source files and recompiling and re-running them immediately on remote device. With vscode I have all my source projects located on remote devices in remote offices and it works great. synchronizing is much slower.

I too edit remote files directly when it is a quick fix. However if I have to work on a file continuously, I work on a local version. Unless you setup rsync with cron, it only syncs when you run it. Unison runs in the background and syncs as soon as the file changes.

@user68186  What is "continuously"? If I need to read a remote log file once a day or edit a config file once a week or modify a script when I need it, is it worse performing continuous background synchronization on hundreds of files over VPN? A good editor should only read remote file once I activated the window without wasting resources on the background.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
